# CSS layout - Dynamic column content defines wrapper height

Tags: html, css

Evening,
I am struggling with a layout (*I always struggle with CSS, curse it to a special kind of hell!*). [I've simplified as best I can and set up a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1uuKlWycPOgPdactcqoI?p=preview). I am after the following...

- Content to full height of the viewport.
- A fixed height `<header>` and `<footer>` with `width: 100%`.
- The `<footer>` is set at the bottom of the viewport.
- The rest of the space between is two columns - **Col A** is fixed width, **Col B** fills the rest of the viewport width and both are `height: 100%`.
- **Col B** contains a `<canvas>` that is centred horizontally.

This is a layout for an Angular app I'm working on and the content in **Col A** is generated based on data in the app so it's height will be always changing. I want the `<footer>` to be pushed down if **Col A** reaches a height greater than the viewport but otherwise the `<footer>` should remain at `bottom: 0`.

[In my example](http://plnkr.co/edit/1uuKlWycPOgPdactcqoI?p=preview) you see the `<footer>` is stuck to the bottom but if you reduce the viewport height it is eventually blocked by the `<canvas>` element. I want the same thing to happen with the contents of **Col A** on the left. As elements are added I want the `<footer>` to push down if necessary and if the viewport shrinks I want the **Col A** content to block the `<footer>`.

At the moment **Col A** is `position: absolute` so blocks nothing but if I set it to `relative` it loses its full height (the green background). Basically I've been going round in circles with this pretty much all day. It has long since stopped being an interesting problem and has become a real pain so if you can offer any advice at all I would be very grateful.

Not sure if I have explained myself very well. I will clarify if I can, just ask.

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use absolute positioning. Use flexbox with `flex-grow: 1` when you want something grow to fill available space.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body, #page-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#page-wrapper {
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #ff6900;
}
header {
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
  height: 40px;
}
#ui-wrapper {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  width: 120px;
}
.filler {
  background-color: gold;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 3px double;
}
#display-wrapper {
  margin-top: 40px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
footer {
  background-color: #8e8e8e;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div id="ui-wrapper">
    <div class="filler">x</div>
    <div class="filler">x</div>
    <div class="filler">x</div>
    <div class="filler">x</div>
    <div class="filler">x</div>
    <div class="filler">x</div>
    <div class="filler">x</div>
    <div class="filler">x</div>
    <div class="filler">x</div>
  </div>
  <div id="display-wrapper">
    <canvas width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: May I suggest you change `min-height` to `height` in `html` rule and `flex-grow: 1` to `flex: 1 0 auto` in `html, body, #page-wrapper` rule. With that change this will work on IE11 too (defeat its _min-width_ bug and always be full viewport height even with small content)

Comment: @LGSon Like this? I don't have IE on Linux to test.

Comment: That seems to be bang on, thank you. I'll admit in an embarrassed mumble that I never even heard of flexbox except in passing. I really try to leave the CSS to others if I can - nasty, hacky business it always seems to me. Looks like I'll be spending the morning on [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion, based on a Head-Body-Foot with Left-Main-Right containers. The example can be tweaked with sizes, paddings and colours of your choice (Right container set to zero width, as it's not used). Content Canvas is centered both horizontally and vertically.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/javierrey/t8a74d93/11/

HTML:

```
<div class="lay">
  <div class="lay-head">
    <div class="lay-main">
    Header
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lay-body">
    <div class="lay-left">
    Left
    </div>
    <div class="lay-right">
    </div>
    <div class="lay-main">
      <canvas class="content">
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lay-foot">
    <div class="lay-main">
    Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* General default (Bootstrap compatible) */

html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
body {margin: 0; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; background-color: #ffffff;}
body, input, textarea, keygen, select, button {color: #555555;}
* {box-sizing: border-box; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px;}
*:focus {outline: 0;}
a {text-decoration: none;}
textarea {resize: none; overflow: auto;}

/* Default Layout */

.lay {position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 100%;}
.lay-head {position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 0;}
.lay-foot {position: absolute; overflow: hidden; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 0;}
.lay-body {overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;}
.lay-left {overflow: hidden; float: left; height: 100%; width: 0;}
.lay-right {overflow: hidden; float: right; height: 100%; width: 0;}
.lay-main {overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; width: auto; height: 100%;}

/* Custom Layout */

.lay>.lay-head, .lay>.lay-foot {
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.lay>.lay-body {
  padding-top: 32px; /* Same as head height */
  padding-bottom: 32px; /* Same as foot height */
}

.lay>.lay-body>.lay-left {
  width: 150px;
}

.lay>.lay-body>.lay-right {
  width: 0;
}

/* Content */

.lay>.lay-body>.lay-main {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px; /* Custom: 0, 20px */
}

.lay>.lay-body>.lay-main>.content {
  position: relative; /* Center vertically (1) */
  top: 50%; /* Center vertically (2) */
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* Center vertically (3) */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

/* Theming */

body {
  background: #ffffff;
}

body, input, textarea, keygen, select, button {
  color: #777777;
}

.lay>.lay-head, .lay>.lay-foot {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #cccccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
}

.lay>.lay-body>.lay-left {
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  color: #555555;
}

.lay>.lay-body>.lay-main>.content {
  background-color: #333333;
}

/**/
```